# Access header on redirect response with tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient?

Tags: python, cookies, tornado, asynchttpclient

I have a case that I need to extract cookies from a redirect response(login page, for example).

I have read the doc, even the source code, but still can't find a way to do this.

By default, `AsyncHTTPClient` will follow the redirect and return the redirected response, which didn't contain `Set-Cookie` thus useless. If given option `follow_redirects=False`, it will throw an `HTTPError` just because the response code isn't 200. I also tried the blocking `HTTPClient` class, it's same.

So, what's the right way to do this? I think it's common way that server will send `Set-Cookie` header along side with a `Location` header when a user login successfully.

Could it be considered as a bug? Or, design deficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the HTTPResponse object, including its headers, from the HTTPError.response attribute:

http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.HTTPError

The following code demonstrates this:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient, HTTPError

client = AsyncHTTPClient()


@gen.coroutine
def fetch():
    try:
        yield client.fetch('http://tornadoweb.org', follow_redirects=False)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print 'response:'
        print e.response
        print
        print 'headers:'
        print e.response.headers


IOLoop.current().run_sync(fetch)
```

Comment: And in Tornado 4.1 (not yet released, but it will be within a few days), you'll be able to pass `raise_error=False`) so non-200 response codes won't raise an exception.